# Error 10004 when creating a Hive table in Alteryx

Tags: hive, alteryx

I have an issue with a table creation in Alteryx. I use a *Write Data In-Db* tool at the end of my workflow (like in many others I already made). The target table doesn't exist yet. I have tried *Create new table* as well as *Overwrite Table (Drop)* but it's the same result.

There is the error which I can't explain :

```
Error: Write Data In-DB (184): Error running PreSQL on "NoTable": [Simba][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:14507 Invalid table alias or column reference 'Sinistre': (possible column names are: nrcl, nrefrcl, drcprcl, dstrcl, dcrercl, nchm, nsoc, ccnlrcl, cdmnrcl, ldmnrcl, cetarcl, theprircl, thescdrcl, lthescdrcl, dhchg)
```

I don't know why it mentions "Sinistre" as no column or data is named this way in my results. Also there are the columns of the data I try to write :

```
1   nom_expert  V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
2   num_expert  Double  8   In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
3   date_contact    V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
4   typo_chemise    V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
5   nom_contact V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
6   prenom_contact  V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
7   ref_evenement   V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
8   email_contact   V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
9   tel_mobile_contact  V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
10  tel_domicile_contact    V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
11  num_soc V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;   
12  entite  V_String    255 In-DB:DB=ehivedb;
```

Do you have any idea what could cause this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer myself as I found the cause of the error. Maybe it can help someone.

In a *Connect In-Db* tool at the left of my workflow, a word in a *WHERE* clause was within double quotes... Apparently this causes Hive to believe it's another column. I just changed to single quotes and it now works.

Thing is, the error only appears at the end tool when writing to a table, that's why the cause was not obvious (I have more than a dozen source tables, at the left of a big workflow). 
So it can cause an error for Hive, even if the data and columns available at the end of the wf is perfectly ok for Alteryx.